# Getting EntityTooSmall error even though part size is more than 5MB except the last part

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using a multipart upload with each part having minimum 5MB data except the last part, even then I am getting Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size.

Below are the parts and sizes

Uploaded part id: 1 StreamLength: 5378091
Uploaded part id: 2 StreamLength: 5261827
Uploaded part id: 3 StreamLength: 5284709
Uploaded part id: 4 StreamLength: 5308622
Uploaded part id: 5 StreamLength: 5243068
Uploaded part id: 6 StreamLength: 5259715
Uploaded part id: 7 StreamLength: 5244506
Uploaded part id: 8 StreamLength: 5245699
Uploaded part id: 9 StreamLength: 1419593

what could be the possible reason for this

Comment: How are you uploading the file?

Comment: Using .Net SDK
using (var client = _amazonS3Factory.CreateAmazonS3(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(data.S3Region)))
                {
                    
                    var completeResult = await client.CompleteMultipartUploadAsync(new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = data.BucketName,
                        Key = GetKey(data.FileName),
                        PartETags = uploadParts.Select(x => new PartETag(x.Key, x.Value)).ToList(),
                        UploadId = uploadId
                    });

Comment: Looks like using multipart upload with input stream is an open issue.